# Copy Windows XP network drivers without installation

Tags: windows, drivers

I want to load network drivers on a Windows XP system but I can't install them the normal way, only copy to the drive when the system is off-line and then start back.

I understand that dropping the .sys file is not sufficient?

Comment: why isnt the normal way an option?

Comment: It is a heavily locked down kiosk image with keyboard and mouse disabled, firewall, etc. Putting all that back might be more effort than sneaking in the drivers.